# Why model has undefined state with repository pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop, nestjs

I'm trying to use repository pattern with TypeScript
Now I have `base.repository` that implements all of the functions that I need, I made it a generic type, and I wanna pass the model while injecting it in `constructor`, but for some reason, while passing the value, I have undefined state of the particular model, what am I doing wrong?

In the `console.log()` it shows me that the model is undefined while in file `register.service.ts` it shows me also undefined, but I passed it as generic.

`register.service.ts`

```
import { BaseRepository } from "../repositories/base.repository";
import { Creator } from '../data/models/Creator'
import { RegisterDto } from "../types/dtos/register.dto";
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RegisterMapper } from '../mappers/register.mapper'
import { errors } from '../errors'
import { mailer } from '../utils/nodemailer'

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
    constructor(
      private readonly repository: BaseRepository<Creator>,
      private readonly mapper: RegisterMapper
    ) { }

    async createAccount (doc: RegisterDto) {
      const emailExist = await this.existByEmail(doc.email)
      if (emailExist) {
        return errors.EMAIL_EXIST()
      }
      const created = await this.repository.create(this.mapper.toDomain(doc))
      await mailer(doc.email)
      return created
    }

    private async existByEmail(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
      console.log(email)
      console.log(this.repository)
      const response = await this.repository.get({ email })
      return !!response.email;
    }
}
```

`base.repository.ts`

```
import { ModelType } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/types'
import { DuplicateKeyError } from '../errors/DuplicateKeyError'
import { DocumentNotFoundError } from '../errors/DocumentNotFoundError'
import { Model } from 'mongoose'
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class BaseRepository<T = any> {
    constructor(
        @Optional() @Inject('MODEL') private Model: any
    ) { }

    async create (object): Promise<T> {
        const Model = this.Model
        console.log(Model)
        const uniqueKey = Model.getUniqueKey ? Model.getUniqueKey() : null
        if (uniqueKey && object[uniqueKey]) {
            const criteria = {
                [uniqueKey]: object[uniqueKey]
            }
            const existing = await Model.findOne(criteria)
            if (existing) {
                throw new DuplicateKeyError(Model, criteria)
            }
        }

        const model = new Model(object)
        return model.save()
    }

    async update (criteria, object, options = {}) {
        const Model = this.Model

        const uniqueKey = Model.getUniqueKey ? Model.getUniqueKey() : '_id'

        const data = { ...object }
        delete data[uniqueKey]
        delete data.createdAt

        return this.updateRaw(criteria, { $set: { ...data } }, options)
    }

    async updateRaw (criteria, data, options = {}) {
        const query = this._getDbQuery(criteria, options)
        const result = await this.Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, { new: true, ...options })

        if (!result) {
            throw new DocumentNotFoundError(this.Model, query)
        }

        return result
    }

    async save (modelInstance) {
        return modelInstance.save()
    }

    async get (criteria, options: any = {}): Promise<T | undefined> {
        console.log(Model)
        const promise = await this.Model.findOne(this._getDbQuery(criteria, options)).exec()

        if (options.select) {
            promise.select(options.select)
        }

        return promise
    }

    async find (criteria, options): Promise<ReturnType<ModelType<T>['find']>> {
        return this.Model.find(this._getDbQuery(criteria, options))
    }

    async resolve (criteria): Promise<T> {
        return this.Model.resolve(this._getDbQuery(criteria))
    }

    async count (query) {
        return this.Model.countDocuments(this._getDbQuery(query))
    }

    async delete (criteria) {
        return this.Model.remove(this._getDbQuery(criteria))
    }

    _getDbQuery (criteria, options: any = {}) {
        if ('getDbQuery' in criteria) {
            const dbQuery = criteria.getDbQuery(options)
            return 'find' in dbQuery
                ? dbQuery.find
                : dbQuery
        } else {
            return criteria
        }
    }

}
```

What should I do to get the actual model in this repository?

Comment: Where do you define the `MODEL` custom provider?

Comment: You've marked Model as `@Optional()`, which means Angular won't error if it can't find a provider for it. It looks like your service actually does require a Model since all the functions need it. It might help you debug if you remove that annotation and tweak your provider until Angular no longer throws an error.
If you show the model provider we can help further

Comment: @I_Adze it is not angular :(

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, I don't know where should I define it. That's what I'm trying to figure out, what should I made, to make it work as I want

Comment: You should make a custom provider in the module that contains this `BaseRepository` class, so that Nest knows what to inject

Comment: I have made providerAggregation function and provided tokens with classes, now it works, thank you very much for answering me! If you want, I can share the solution below for upvoting?

Comment: apologies @DaniilSinelnik nest is based on Angular syntax and modules so I thought it was from a skim read! Sounds like you got your answer but just in case, here's the docs for custom providers in nestjs
https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#custom-providers

My comment does apply if you swap Angular for Nest, if your service required the Model to be defined I would remove the Optional annotation so that nest will error if there is no model available and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added inject tokens in each service before repository Injection

Now the code looks as follows

```
import { BaseRepository } from "../repositories/base.repository";
import { Creator } from '../data/models/Creator'
import { RegisterDto } from "../types/dtos/register.dto";
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RegisterMapper } from '../mappers/register.mapper'
import { errors } from '../errors'
import { mailer } from '../utils/nodemailer'
import { CREATOR } from '../utils'

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
  registerMapper = new RegisterMapper()
    constructor(
      @Inject(CREATOR) private readonly repository: BaseRepository<Creator>,
    ) { }

    async createAccount (doc: RegisterDto) {
      const emailExist = await this.existByEmail(doc.email)
      if (emailExist) {
        return errors.EMAIL_EXIST()
      }
      const created = await this.repository.create(this.mapper.toDomain(doc))
      await mailer(doc.email)
      return created
    }

    private async existByEmail(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
      console.log(email)
      console.log(this.repository)
      const response = await this.repository.get({ email })
      return !!response.email;
    }
}
```

`inject-tokens.ts`

```
export const CREATOR = 'CREATOR'
```